# using mongo-c-driver can not use regular expressions containing forward slash (/)

Tags: c, regex, mongodb, bson

I am trying to use the C-API for MongoDB.  I want to find records with a name matching a regular expression containing slashes (/).  If I run the mongo command line I get 40 results for the query:

```
 db.test_006.find({'name':/^\/TEST::TOP:NEWSTAT\/_data_[0-9]*/})
```

which is correct. When I try to code this in C I can not get it to match.

using:

```
bson_append_regex( &query, "name","/TEST::TOP:NEWSTAT/" , "" )
```

I find all the records and more.

All combinations of `\\/`  or even `[/]`  or `[\\/]`  do not find any records.  I also tried `\\x2F`.

Is this just broken ?  Am I missing something ?   There is plenty of information about compiling regular expressions to use with other languages (python, java, etc...)

Thanks,
-Josh

Comment: I don't know anything about MongoDB, but what happened to the `_data_[0-9]*` at the end of your original query?

Comment: Mongo matches them since there is no end of line in the regex
-Josh